# Inserting into a vector of maps

Tags: c++, templates, vector, insert, maps

I have a vector of maps that I need to insert into.  This is the part of my code that is giving me my errors.  Note that RGB is a struct holding 3 unsigned chars, red, green, and blue.  When I try to insert, such as int he code below, I get these errors:

**support.cpp:231:38: error: 'i' cannot appear in a constant-expression
support.cpp:231:39: error: an array reference cannot appear in a constant-expression
support.cpp:231:42: error: 'PPM::img' cannot appear in a constant-expression
support.cpp:231:46: error: 'i' cannot appear in a constant-expression
support.cpp:231:47: error: an array reference cannot appear in a constant-expression
support.cpp:231:48: error: template argument 1 is invalid
support.cpp:231:48: error: template argument 2 is invalid**

I have tried searching all over the internet for a solution, but I can only find instances of this error with switch statements.  Any help would be appreciated

```
 vector<map<int, RGB> > timesClosest;
 timesClosest.resize(qcolors.size());

int counts[img.size()];


for (int j = 0; j < qcolors.size(); j++)
{
    int counts[img.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < img.size(); i++)
    {
        counts[i] = 0;
        if (indexQC[i] == j)
        {
            counts[i]++;
        }
    }
    //now add this to the map
    for (int i = 0; i < img.size(); i++)
    {
        int c = counts[i];
        timesClosest[i].insert(pair<counts[i], img[i]>);


    }

}
```

Comment: what's the declaration of `indexQC`?

Comment: int indexQC[img.size()]

I also forgot to mention img is a vector<RGB>, and it's all the pixels of a ppm file.

Comment: Why ddin't you use vector for what it is designed to do, and that is a dynamic array?  `int counts[img.size()];`  Use a vector instead.

Comment: @gsoble Also, where is line 231?

Comment: Because counts won't change size.

Comment: @gsoble It doesn't matter if counts doesn't change size.  You cannot declare an array with a runtime expression.  Your code is not legal C++.

Comment: @gsoble Which line is 231?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue is that you cannot declare arrays with a runtime expression denoting the number of elements.

Instead, use `std::vector`.  You're using it anyway, but for some reason, you didn't use it where it truly needs to be used:

Instead of:

`int counts[img.size()];`

Do this:

`std::vector<int> counts(img.size());`

Comment: Well... some compilers (e.g. GNU) support such arrays as a non-portable/Standard extension... choosing to use it when `std::vector<>` is available is debatable practice but more worthy of a comment than an answer, given no ostensible relevance to the error message in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You're inserting into the template arguments of `timesClosest`. The insert should be

```
timesClosest[i].insert(std::make_pair(counts[i], img[i]));
```

Comment: That still doesn't fix my issue, unfortunately.

Comment: @gsoble you're also declaring `int counts[img.size()];` twice. Once at the top and again inside the first for loop.

Comment: Thanks, didn't catch that.

Comment: @gsoble Are you still getting the same compiler errors?

Comment: Yeah, still am unfortunately.

Comment: @gsoble I think it's time for you to post a *complete* but minimal example that shows the error.  The following link, with the changes I suggested in my answer plus the answer given here, shows that the code compiles with no errors.  http://ideone.com/Lo3C8W